# Progress SQL no lock

Tags: progress-database

I need to be able to run a query without table locking. How would I accomplish this.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM pub.my_table with no lock 
    WHERE my_table.description LIKE 'white bunnies'
    ORDER BY created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, the query syntax would need to look like this.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM pub.my_table
    WHERE my_table.description LIKE 'white bunnies'
    ORDER BY created_at
    WITH (NOLOCK)
```